# Commit changes with lock keeping

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, transactions, locking

I have an application that works with database table like
`Id, state, procdate, result`

When there is a need to process some data, the app sets state to `PROCESSING`. After processing the result of processing is being set to `result` column and the state goes to `STANDBY`.

To do the first set to `PROCESSING`  I start the transaction, do `select for update`, then update the state and procdate.
Then I do the work and using `selection for update` update the state and the result.

The processing may take up to 5 minutes. The state switching is needed to see how many rows are in progress. The problem is that another request for processing may occur and it has to wait until the first processing will end.
So I want to keep row locked. If I will make the select for update for locking just after I commit the processing state the second request may intercept and lock the row.

So how can I both keep the locking and commit the changes?

Comment: You can't do that.  Maybe you need to re-think your design?

Comment: That's sad. Maybe I need. But i don't know how. Any books or articles or conference videos?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to handle this with your design.  Here is an idea.

1. You records initially have a status, say 'READY', and a processing id, null initially.
2. When you start, update the status to 'PROCESSING', and update the id to a value for the job run, this can come from a sequence within Oracle, such that it is unique for your process run.  commit.
3. the process runs, with the same id, and selects the status 'PROCESSING' and the same as it's defined processing id.  Complete processing, update status to 'COMPLETE' (or 'STANDBY' as you have it).  Commit.

This allows a second process to select new 'READY' records and set them for its own processing without interference with the already running process.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two approaches I have taken. (I provide a third, but have never had to take that approach.)

1) Why not exit the transaction after committing the changes.

2) If option 1 is not viable, then you could simply:

- COMMIT the changes
- attempt to re-acquire the lock, if you fail, leave the screen, else just continue.

3) If it is absolutely imperative that no one can ever acquire the lock in the middle of a commit... you could actually lock another object. I will admit, I have never had to take this approach, but it would be as follows:

Initial phase

- LOCK GLOBALOBJECT
- Attempt to Acquire record lock for table
- UNLOCK GLOBALOBJECT
- Test to see if record lock was attained

Phase for committing the change

- LOCK GLOBALOBJECT
- COMMIT change
- Acquire record lock for table
- UNLOCK GLOBALOBJECT
- Test to see if record lock was attained (Should never happen...)

I have never needed this kind of logic, and I really do not like it since it requires a GLOBAL locking object for this table.  Again, it depends on your code, and the criticality of someone being able to commit changes while still being in the transaction.

However, just make sure you are not gold-plating your code when simply exiting out of the transaction after commiting a change would be fine for your stakeholders.